# Grails commands under Idea fail with a "NoSuchMethodError" for "getAndPut" in the "EvictableCache" class

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, groovy

I'm trying to get an existing project working on a new platform (MacOS, M1) with Idea as the IDE. (I'm extremely new to Idea, but I'm getting help from other project developers.)

For a particular module in the project, any attempt to run pretty much any Grails command fails with an exception:

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.EvictableCache.getAndPut(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/memoize/MemoizeCache$ValueProvider;)Ljava/lang/Object

I have verified (to the extent I know how) that there's only one Groovy installation on the machine, and it's version 2.4.14 installed by sdkman. (Grails is 2.5.6.) Running the grails command as part of the Idea build (ie, from clicking "Build" or whatever inside the IDE) and running the grails command in the module top-level directory from the command line have exactly the same results.

I don't have much (well, any) experience with grails or groovy, but to me a "NoSuchMethodError" means that some piece of code was compiled against a different version of that class (`EvictableCache`) than the version that's actually in the jar file when grails runs. There are groovy `.jar` files in the project directory, but their presence seems to make no difference; it always gets that exception.

I'm using the Azul zulu8 JDK, downloaded from Azul directly. Formerly I had been using a version installed with `brew` but that made no difference.

Any ideas as to how to locate the `.class` file with the attempted call to `getAndPut()` in `EvictableCache` would be welcome.

*edit* — as I was looking at the stack traces from running a command, I noticed something. Again, my `groovy` is 2.4.14, as I can verify with `groovy -version`. At the top of one of my stack traces (maybe more than one) I see that the attempted call to `getAndPut()` is coming from a class called `AbstractExtensionMethodCache`.  Well, as far as I can tell, that class did not become part of Groovy until version 3. So clearly something is messed up.

Comment: What Groovy SDK version [do you see in the module dependencies](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206224119-How-to-configure-new-Groovy-SDK?page=1#community_comment_360000152759)? It looks like your projects targets a different Groovy version or there is a mismatch between the Groovy and Grails versions you are trying to use.

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes thanks, I've been trying to figure that out. I'm about to update the question with an interesting piece of information.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you for that link, but when I look at that module in Idea, I don't see Groovy in the "Add framework support" dialog. I *think* that's because the support is already there because it has Grails support, but I don't understand enough to be certain about that.

Comment: See what libraries are present in the module dependencies.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you. When I start from a clean slate with the overall project, and I add Grails framework support, Idea proceeds to download a bunch of Groovy support, and it seems to want to get groovy 4.0.2. Sure enough, that `AbstractExtensionMethodCache` class is right there in `groovy-4.0.2.jar`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder weird thing is that it doesn't seem to affect other developers. However that's definitely something to go on. Thank you so much!